# Collaboration in Eclipse via ECF

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-ecf

I wanted to use the DocShare plugin so I installed the ECF SDK in Eclipse Luna and tried adding my google account using the File->New->XMPPS and added my google account information to log in but I get the error "Container Connect" has encountered an error.

Do i need to include anything except my email address in the field for User-ID?
I would love any help on this issue as I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it working.

BTW, I also tried adding the details of my account into the XMPP dialogue with the same result.

EDIT: I just realized that I also need to enter a port with my email address but I have almost no knowledge of ports and have no idea what port to assign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowing "Less Secure Apps" in my google settings did the job. Am now connected to my Google Account through Eclipse. Recieved an email that asked me to allow this.